# How can runtime type checks be implemented?

Tags: implementation, object-oriented, rtti

Most if not all OO languages have some way to determine whether an object belongs to a given class at runtime. In some languages -- both interpreted (like JS) and compiled (like Objective-C) -- classes are objects that exist at runtime, and an object can just be asked for its class ([`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) and [`class`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571950-class?language=objc) respectively).

However, I'm curious what other strategies exist. For example, I don't believe C++ has class objects, so how does `dynamic_cast` work?

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzJL-8WbpuU) is a good talk from Cppcon about `dynamic_cast` implementation.

Answer (score 4):

## Fat Pointers

A "fat pointer" is a pointer that stores additional data besides an address. For the purposes of dynamic dispatch and type checking, this data can be a pointer to a vtable which stores type information such as associated functions and a type ID. This approach is taken by Go and Rust, among others.

An example adapted from Rust's documentation:

```rs
use std::any::Any;
use std::mem::size_of;

pub fn print_if_string(s: &dyn Any) {
    // `&dyn Any` is a fat pointer, the size of two 'regular' pointers
    assert!(size_of::<&dyn Any>() == 2 * size_of::<&String>());

    println!("Object has type id `{:?}`", s.type_id());
    
    if let Some(string) = s.downcast_ref::<String>() {
        println!("It's a string({}): '{}'", string.len(), string);
    } else {
        println!("Not a string...");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type ID in Rust? In Swift, as in ObjC, it’s a pointer to a type object.

Comment: As an implementation detail, Rust's `TypeId` is currently a 64-bit integer which the compiler guarantees is unique for every type.